# Link in chat with trailing space shows markdown instead of link text

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, markdown-rendering

When I put a link into chat that has a space at the end of the link text, the chat window briefly shows the link as expected and then a second or two later changes to show the markdown.

Below are my two test strings. Notice that both have a space after `JavaScript` in the square brackets. The second string also has a trailing space at the end of the string. Both result in the same behavior.

```
[JavaScript ](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/)
[JavaScript ](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/)
```

The message is posted and looks like this:

[image: Chat link as expected]

A second later, the message changes to display this instead:

[image: Chat link as displayed]

The link to this message can be found [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2721997#2721997)